# What is difference between resonant and non resonant antennas?

Tags: antenna, communication, digital-communications, telecommunications, antenna-array

I don't know if it's right place to ask it, but I searched google and books the answer I get seems to be like resonant antenna have small bandwidth and have standing wave instead non resonant antennas have wider bandwidth and travelling waves. What I don't get that how should it affect my choice of choosing one over other for a particular situation, like what I lose when I choose one over other and what I gain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A non-electrically-resonant antenna is when the antenna is used at its optimum "natural" frequency. Example: a half-wave dipole where the incoming signal wavelength corresponds to twice the antenna length. In these circumstances, the dipole appears as a resistance fairly close to 74 ohms and, either side of its "natural" resonant frequency, it might look a little capacitive or a little inductive but, the main component of its impedance is resistance. This makes it difficult to directly electrically tune to gain any benefit and, because of this, it has a naturally "decent" bandwidth.

Another example is the quarter-wave monopole antenna used on FM radios to receive 88 to 108 MHz broadcast stations. These are non-electrically-resonant and have a decent bandwidth.

A good example of an electrically-resonant antenna is the old-fashioned crystal radio antenna. Typically it's a monopole but, because it's being used to receive transmissions in the 1 MHz or lower part of the spectrum, it's physical length is well-short of a quarter wavelength and, because of this, its dominant impedance is capacitive. The received signal voltage is also significantly smaller than a proper quarter-wave monopole but, because crystal radios use a tuned inductor, the arrangement of short-antenna (dominated by capacitive reactance) and the tuning inductor magnify the low signal voltage significantly. Together they are an electrically-resonant circuit. They can be "selective" enough to tune across lower the frequency bands and receive each transmission without much co-channel interference.

The decision to choose one over the other is usually down to accommodating the space required for the antenna. If there isn't much room to have a full-length "natural" antenna, then you will choose a "short" antenna and possibly implement a direct tuning regime to select the desired station.

Comment: Sir I got what you emphasised but how do I compare it with a not resonant  antenna .

Comment: I covered both in my answer. First: non-electrically resonant and then below that the electrically-resonant antenna @SUNITAGUPTA

Comment: Sir I pardon to say but from "A good example..... " i.e. in third para didn't you said that how a not resonant antenna can also be made highly tuned.

Comment: @SUNITAGUPTA - OK, I've added a phrase in brackets after "short-antenna" : (dominated by capacitive reactance) - does this now make more sense? Do you understand that a capacitor and inductor used together can make a highly resonant circuit?

Comment: Sir I know they will form a tuned circuit but won't it be much better to use a not resonant antenna then and insert a inductor in parallel. This will give then ability to tune by carrying inductance also a variable resistor in series with inductor can be used set required bandwidth. Practically this way resonant antennas should become not existant, but as you mentioned they are used extensively I just wan't to know the reason why.

Comment: What is the compromise I'll have to make choosing either one and what I'll gain by doing it .

Comment: I've added a final paragraph - it's down to size.

Comment: Sir should our decision simply books down to space requirement. That is if non resonant antenna offers everything good why not simply use it. Shouldn't my decision be based on more objetivo things like directivity, radiation resistance, Effeciency, Cross Polarisation ratio .

Comment: These things are barely affected and remember that this is a question and answer site. If you now want to explore how an antenna might subtly change its characteristics based on loading impedance then ask a new question. I walk away from questions that evolve excessively because it wastes too much of my time. It's just a nudge to remember what this site is about - it's not a forum or talking shop.